# Two-dimensional array/dictionary combination

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Is there a way to define a two-dimensional array/dictionary combination, wherein the first value is enumerative and the second associative? The end result would ideally look like this, where the first is a simple index, and the second a key->value pair.

```
data[0]["Name"] = ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so a `list` of `dict`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding my comment, a `list` of `dict`s:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{'first_name':'greg', 'last_name':'schlaepfer'},
...                  {'first_name':'michael', 'last_name':'lester'}]
>>>
>>> list_of_dicts[0]['first_name']
'greg'
```

Comment: I was just going to say, you answered my question with your initial question--I just didn't know the terminology, but a list of dictionaries is exactly what I'm after--thanks for the example, and your help!

Comment: Please select an answer as correct to close the question

Comment: Yup--it just made me wait 10 minutes before I could select yours as the answer. I didn't think I'd get an answer within a minute of posting!

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- a list of dictionaries:

```
>>> LoD=[{c:i for i,c in enumerate(li)} for li in ('abc','def','ghi')]
>>> LoD
[{'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'a': 0}, {'f': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': 0}, {'g': 0, 'i': 2, 'h': 1}]
>>> LoD[2]['g']
0
>>> LoD[2]['h']
1
```

Be sure that you use `dict` methods on the dicts and `list` methods on the lists:

OK:

```
>>> LoD[2]['new']='new value'
>>> LoD
[{'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'a': 0}, {'f': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': 0}, {'g': 0, 'new': 'new value', 'i': 2, 'h': 1}]

>>> LoD.append({'new key':'new value'})
>>> LoD
[{'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'a': 0}, {'f': 2, 'e': 1, 'd': 0}, {'g': 0, 'new': 'new value', 'i': 2, 'h': 1}, {'new key': 'new value'}]
```

No go:

```
>>> LoD['new']='test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

>>> LoD[2].append('something')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dicts = [  {"name": "Tom", "age": 10 },
           {"name": "Tom", "age": 10 },
           {"name": "Tom", "age": 10 }  ]

print dicts[0]['name']
```

Essentially, you would be creating a list of dictionaries. Props to [mhlester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3130539/mhlester) for having the right answer earlier as a comment.